# Dual monitor adapter compatibility for laptop

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, adapter, ubuntu-18.04, hp-spectre

I bought a [ICZI USB-C to HDMI + VGA adapter](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07HC9XX8W/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) for my HP Sprectre x360 Model 13-ap0xxx, but the system does not detect the adapter. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

The USB-C to HDMI display adapter that came with the box works fine with a single monitor.

So what is the difference between these hardware components that makes one detect and the other not? What specifications should I be looking for to identify an adapter that will be compatible with my laptop?

Comment: You want to do homework and read reviews for any hardware you buy online when reviews are available and see what others say about this and issues with it. You should also reach out to the vendor, explain to them the hardware and operating system you are using, and see if they have a solution or you can return for a refund if it doesn't work with your setup. Perhaps taking your machine with you to a local electronic store and talking to the sales people that are suppose to be experts in the hardware and they can confirm something, you can buy and test right there.

Comment: This issue is likely compatibility with the hardware or maybe drivers from the OS side but I'm not sure. There are also UEFI or BIOS settings you can adjust and play with since you already have the hardware and can test every possible variation of settings. Look for an updated driver, read more reviews, google research, etc. Unless you have a hardware product that you but that states 100% compatibility of the hardware you have, etc. then these are some of the common sense type of action you can take before making the purchase otherwise test more setting since you have it already and can.

Comment: Additionally, based on some of the Amazon reviews from the link you provided with the question, there are 16% extremely negative 1 star votes and people talking about this hardware being defective in some cases. Perhaps you were one of the 16% here and your defective hardware is so defective, the PC does not event recognize it being plugged in, etc. Seems too broad to tell for sure what the issue is but otherwise just use some good old common sense with your hardware shopping and hardware compatibility journey for correlated hardware you are going to buy for this system. Good luck!!